# VB 2008 Express edition vs VB 6

Tags: vb.net

Can any tell me what are the advantages of **VB.NET**(2008 Express Edition) over **VB 6**?
Thank you

Comment: This is like asking for the advantage of a nice new Cadillac over your beaten-up old Yugo.  If you have no clue then you ought to take a test-drive.  They did move the pedals around btw.

Comment: If you've no experience with either, just go straight to VB.Net 2012 (why 2008?).

Answer (score 3):

Good comparison you can find in Wiki:
[VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VB.NET)

In short: the greatest feature in VB.NET is Managed Code. It also contains a little difference between Long and Integer in VB6 and VB.NET. There are also many small syntax changes (for example, VB.NET support structured exception handling).

Answer (score 3):

VB6 is a old fashioned programming software from microsoft. It doesn't use as a base .NET framework which is used on every machine. Also visit Wkipedia VB

Answer (score 3):

.NET have multithreading and more functional components (for work with network for example).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic is a third-generation event-driven programming language and integrated development environment (IDE) from Microsoft for its Component Object Model (COM) programming model first released in 1991, final release was version 6 in 1998 (VB6) and declared legacy during 2008.

Visual Basic.net is part of the .net framework (like C# or F#), first released in 2002, with constant Microsoft updates.

You can use VB.Net in Visual Studio 2008 Express (free) or in any Visual Studio IDE, like the Visual Studio 2017 Community edition (also free).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Visual_Basic_and_Visual_Basic_.NET

VB6 uses legagy frameworks like [Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange) and [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Data_Access_Objects). The VB6 IDE is hard to install on new operating system (original setup gives errors on Windows 7, 8 or 10).